# Make/integromat automation to rename a folder with a discord message as trigger

Tags: browser-automation, make.com, integromat-apps

Ok so I have a daily manual process that my colleagues do which I want to automate so we can save time. I am trying to do it through Make / Integromat.

The process is basically the following:

- A discord channel receives a message which follows this pattern: "Solicitation [ID]: was approved. Code: [Code]". The [ID] and [Code] values will vary.
- I need the automation to get the most recent message on this Discord channel on demand (whenever there are new messages).
- Then, it should search a folder on Dropbox (a fixed path) by the name of "ID".
- Lastly, it should rename this folder which was found to "Code".

I have basic knowledge about programming from years ago, so I will not understand advanced coding.

If you could help me with detailed explanation and step by step it would be greatly appreciated.

I can't seem to get the message's content, it simply returns the ID.
I need help on getting this to work, please!

This is the process I tried. But I can't get past "get message" because I can't access the content, it's blank:

[image]